How do I troubleshoot the "Your system has run out of application memory" pop-up in macOS Sonoma?
How do I troubleshoot the "Your system has run out of application memory" pop-up in macOS Sonoma?
Background:
My employer has provided me with a MacBook Pro M3 Pro with 36 GB of RAM. Incredibly, after about 5 days of uptime, I started getting the "Your system has run out of application memory" pop-up. Activity Monitor said swap was about 36 GB.
It seems likely that something is leaking memory.
Closing the applications showing highest memory usage by both Activity Monitor and ps ax -o vsz,pid,comm | sort -n did not make a significant difference on memory pressure.
After rebooting the machine and using it for several hours, memory pressure is green and swap is 0 bytes. I can't say whether the issue is fixed because, the first time, it happened after several days of uptime.

Welcome, first, have you spoken w/ your IT staff regarding this? They are designated to support you and your work computer, and they may have applied policies to your system that we will not be aware of and that may impact your system's performance. Second, please ask only a single question per post on this site. Edit your question and remove the Bonus, please. You are free to ask more than one question, just each in their own post. Third, what does memory usage look like after you restart?

@music2myear thanks for your comment. I've updated my question per your suggestions. I have not talked to IT about this. However, isn't there a general way to find out how much virtual memory is being used by which processes? This question is more about personal learning than resolving my present issue.

This site is about solving practical and specific problems. We do not know what you imply, we only know what you tell us and what you ask us. You did not ask "how can I find out how much virtual memory is used by any given process", and I'd also guess that question is pretty easily solved via a web search. Please ask the question you want answered, sharing context and details, and the research you have done and attempts that you have made, so we know what not to suggest as an answer.

@music2myear thank you for your perspective. I think the question as it is now reasonably falls within the parameters you outlined. It is a practical question. I happened to mention it's my employer-provided laptop but it just as well could be my personal laptop.

Have you found out that Activity Monitor can display another 5 memory related columns?

@Gilby yes, but I can only make guesses at how to interpret them. The "Memory" one shown by default is always the largest.
